Inverse limit is compact and non-empty
Question: Let $S = \varprojlim S_{i}$, suppose that all sets $S_{i}$ are endowed with a compact Hausdorff topology, that all $S_{i}$ are non-empty and that all maps $f_{ij}$ are continuous. Prove that $S$ is non-empty and compact.
Here, $\varprojlim S_{i} = \{ (s_{i})_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} S_{i} : f_{ij}(s_{i}) = s_{j}, \forall i, j \in I, i \geq j \}$.
Does anybody have a hint on how to prove this? I considered applying Tikhonov's theorem to prove compactness.

$\prod_{i \in I} S_i$ is compact by Tychonoff’s theorem. Clearly $\varprojlim S_i$ is a closed subspace of it, whence compact. For non-emptiness, consider the subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} S_i$ consisting of elements satisfying $f_{ij}(s_i) = s_j$ for finitely many pairs $i \leq j$. Prove it is non-empty. Then prove $\varprojlim S_i$ is nonempty using finite intersection property.

How do you see that it's a closed subspace?

@NaïmFavier $f_{ij}$ is continuous, so $f_{ij}(s_i) = s_j$ is a closed condition.

I am not familiar with the term "closed condition". I guess this is using the fact that any continuous function into a Hausdorff space has a closed graph?

@NaïmFavier Just saying the set of elements satisfying that condition is closed, that’s all. There’s nothing complicated used there. After some slight rephrasing this is just the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed. Not sure what you have in mind here, but this is literally just trivial.

I guess it also uses the fact that limits of nets in a Hausdorff space are unique, or equivalently the diagonal in $X \times X$ is closed when $X$ is Hausdorff. So maybe that’s what you meant?

Yes. In the case of two spaces and a continuous function $f : X \to Y$, the subset ${(x, y) \in X \times Y | f(x) = y}$ is just the graph of $f$, so we need Hausdorfness to conclude that it is closed.

To prove compactness, you can use Tychonoff's theorem to argue that $\prod_{i\in I} S_i$ is compact, then recognize the inverse limit as a closed subspace of the product. To do this, and to prove that the inverse limit is nonempty, consider the sets
$$A_{kj} := \left\{ (s_i) \in \prod_{i\in I} S_i : f_{kj}(s_k) = s_j \right\}$$
and recall that a space $X$ is compact if and only if any collection $\mathcal{C}$ of closed subsets of $X$ satisfying the Finite Intersection Property (intersections of finitely many elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are nonempty) has nonempty total intersection.
I will provide more detail below.
Compactness:

 Let $A_{kj}$ be as above, and recognize that
 $$\varprojlim S_i = \bigcap_{j\leq k} A_{kj}.$$
 We first show that the sets $A_{kj}$ are closed in $\prod_{i\in I} S_i$. To that end, for any $k\in I$ we let $\pi_k : \prod_{i\in I}S_i \to S_k$ be the natural projection. By definition of the product topology, these maps are continuous. The "graph" map $\gamma_{kj} : S_k \to S_k \times S_j$ given by $s_k \mapsto (s_k, f_{kj}(s_k))$ is also continuous since $f_{kj}$ is continous. Then the composition $\gamma_{kj}\circ \pi_k$ is a continuous map $\prod_{i\in I} S_i \to S_k\times S_j$. We can see that $A_{kj}$ is the preimage of the graph $\Gamma_{kj} := \{(s_k, f_{kj}(s_k)) : s_k \in S_k\}$ under this map, and since the spaces $S_i$ are Hausdorff, $\Gamma_{kj}$ is a closed subspace of $S_k\times S_j$. Thus $A_{kj}$ is closed as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map. Since the inverse limit is the intersection of all these closed spaces, it is a closed subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}S_i$ and thus compact.

Nonempty:

 We use the sets $A_{kj}$ from before, and use the Finite Intersection Property definition of compactness. Since $\varprojlim S_i = \bigcap A_{kj}$ and the sets $A_{kj}$ are closed, it suffices to show that these satisfy the finite intersection property. Suppose we have $A_{k_1j_1}, \ldots, A_{k_nj_n}$; since $I$ is a directed set, any pair of indices has a common upper bound. We can induct to show that there exists $\ell\in I$ such that $\ell\geq k_m$ for $m=1,\ldots,n$. Let $s_{\ell} \in S_\ell$ and set $s_{k_m} = f_{\ell k_m}(s_{\ell})$, $s_{j_m}=f_{k_mj_m}(s_{k_m})$ for each $m$. By the Axiom of Choice, the product
 $$\prod_{I \setminus \{\ell, k_1,\ldots,k_n, j_1,\ldots, j_n\}} S_i$$
 is nonempty, so we can choose $(s_i)$ in this product and set the remaining components $s_\ell, s_{k_m}, s_{j_m}$ to those described above. This gives an element of the intersection $\bigcap_{m=1}^n A_{k_mj_m}$, so the collection $\{A_{kj} : k\geq j\}$ satisfies the Finite Intersection Property as claimed.


Hi @Shyram R. Thank you for your solution. I was wondering if you could elaborate a bit more on the part where you apply the Axiom of Choice, I don't really understand why this gives an element of the intersection $\cap_{m=1}^{n} A_{k_{m}j_{m}}$ so that it is non-empty.

@ByteBlitzer To construct an element of the intersection we need to construct a tuple $(s_i)$ which satisfies the conditions $s_{j_m} = f_{k_mj_m}(s_{k_m})$. Since the inverse system has the property that maps are coherent, the process of finding a common upper bound and then descending ensures that there will be no "conflicts" in the case that some of the indices $k_m$ or $j_m$ coincide. For the remaining indices, we simply choose any element of $S_i$, as there are no other conditions for these indices. By construction, this satisfies exactly the conditions needed to be in the intersection.
